# Using R Programming Language with FANN Neural Network Library

Tags: r

I do a lot of computational intelligence research.  I have used Matlab almost exclusively as my programming medium for a decade or so.  I am now trying to move to OSS.  I have settled on R as my new environment.

After a long search for neural net software, the only Matlab-comparable OSS packages are Stuttgart NN and FANN (this can be debated another time =).  The former doesn't appear to be maintained so I'd like to go with the latter. So my question is:

Does anyone have experience using R and FANN?

FANN has C++ bindings and R seems to have a couple of packages for a C++ interface, but since I'm a R newbie I need an idea of where exactly to start.  Any guidance or recommendations would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know anything abuot FANN but I can assure you that R has an actively maintained interface to the Stuttgart Neural Net Simulator (SNNS) library via the 
[RSNNS](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RSNNS) package --- as RSNNS happens to employ the 
[Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) package for interfacing R and C++ which I am involved in.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  BTW I meant SNNS does not appear to be maintained.  [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) has speed as it's claim to fame and wrappers for several languages (incl. C++) although it is written in C.

Comment: Sure. You could look at how RSNNS wraps SNNS to try 'RFANN' --- but building that may be more work than just *using* RSNNS.

Comment: I also came across a sourceforge project called [rfann](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rfann/).  It doesn't appear to be maintained.

Comment: My bad.  The developer of rfann still has an active interest in the project [at the FANN forum.](http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=651&p=2873#p2873)

Comment: Cool. Maybe he and you can even take a look at RSNNS and see if you like what Rcpp offers for interfacing C++ to R.